# Fill form and retrieve result using Requests

Tags: python, forms, python-requests

I have a website form that I want to fill with some data and retrieve the result.

I was able to figure out the form id/class in the html, but I don't know how to set the content to it and send it back to the server and retrieve the result

I'm using Request to get the url and BeautifulSoup, to parse the html.

Here what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_form(raw_resp):
    soup = bs(raw_resp.text)
    soup = soup.body.find_all('textarea', attrs={'id':'objetos'})
    form = soup[0]
    return getattr(form,'attrs')

payload = {
    'object ID': 'SOMEIDHERE',
    }

url = 'http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/'

with requests.session() as s:
    resp = s.get(url)
    form = get_form(resp)
    for key,value in form.items():
        print "%s = %s"%(key,value)
```

Output:

```
style = text-transform:uppercase;
name = objetos
onblur = this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()
onkeydown = if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.form.submit(); return false; }
id = objetos
class = [u'f8col', u'fldSRO', u'f3row']
```

I want to pass the object_ID to this form and retrieve the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While inspecting the "Network" tab in browser developer tools, you can see that you need to make a `POST` request to the same URL providing `objetos` and `btnPesq` post parameters:

```
with requests.session() as s:
    s.get(url)

    response = s.post('http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/resultado.cfm', 
                      data={'objetos': payload['object ID'], 
                            'btnPesq': 'Buscar'})
    print response.content
```

As a side note, there are related tools that can help you to stay on a higher level and submit the form, see:

- [`MechanicalSoup`](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup)
- [`robobrowser`](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser)

Both are based on `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Upvoted for using `requests.session()`. Getting the OP started on the right track.

Comment: Could you explain how you get the `btnPesq:Buscar`?

Comment: @f.rodrigues this is something you can leave hardcoded, the `objectos` is what you should focus on - it should contain your `object ID`.

Comment: I mean so in the future I can find it myself and avoid having to ask again here.

Comment: @f.rodrigues ah, sure, use browser developer tools, open network tab, submit a form and see what request is being sent. Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh I see. Only thing is that the response is returning the same page. With `pageid = '1C658B24-5056-9163-891FB9FC40735A16'`, it should be `'1C658B24-5056-9163-891FB9FC40735A16';`, which is the result page

Comment: It raises `requests.exceptions.MissingSchema [...]`
then I added `http://` to it but raises 
`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))`